Supabase: why is .eq() is negating my query?
I am using supabase python library to do a simple matching query:
from supabase import Client

query = supabase.table("jobs").select('*')
if job_id is not None:
    query = query.eq("job_id", job_id)

but to my surprise this is the query generated by supabase:
query.params._dict is {'select': ['*'], 'job_id': ['not.eq.1']}
I tried it with other expressions but only .eq() seems to be behaving like this.

It shouldn't, that should only happen with .neq(). Make sure you didn't mistype it.

im not. query = supabase.table("jobs").select('*').eq("job_id", job_id) works as expected but not when i chain it like above. I submitted a github issue but no response.

I'm not at all familiar with the Python SDK of Supabase, but it could be a bug on the SDK, so it might be worth opening an issue on GitHub.

Doing this backwards would be an extremely serious bug, it's a really basic operation. It's hard to imagine how the code would get released like this.

issue was closed and no response from the team i just dont understand how it can behave like this and nobody bothers replying on github

I had a similar issue where I was getting the correct values when i wrote the query directly in supabase, but when i tried to run it locally it wouldn't retrieve anything. For me it was because of it being related to the row-level security policy set.
